# Cycles doesn't render geometry-nodes correctly

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, geometry-nodes

I made a rocky wall using geometry nodes.

When I wanted to render it, I noticed that it renders out correctly using the Eevee render engine. **But using cycles, the rocks did not look the same as they did in the viewport.**

Is there any way to solve this problem?

Here's how the imaged rendered out using the Eevee render engine
[image]

And this is how it looks like using cycles
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why. But to fix it, I had to turn off smooth shading.